# Cannot set cookies while developing on localhost

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-webapi, samesite

Unable to set cookies on Windows 10 localhost performing ASP.NET Core 2.2 C# development in Visual Studio 2019. SameSite is not set on the development server. The code I am using to set cookies is as follows:
var sessionId = new CookieHeaderValue("sessionid", session)
{ Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10) };

```
            var sessionIp = new CookieHeaderValue("sessionIp", ipAddress)
            { Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10) };
            request.Method = "GET";
            WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I would appreciate any insights regarding workarounds for this issue.

Comment: Hi @TedTakacs, are you sure you use asp.net core instead of asp.net? Because your code seems working in asp.net.

Comment: hello @TedTakacs. I just posted a similar question yesterday. Reach out if you figure out anything and I'll do the same.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791605/net-core-cross-site-cookie-not-being-set-by-chrome-or-firefox