# .Net Core Cross Site Cookie Not Being Set by Chrome or Firefox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

I am trying to use a cookie sent from an Asp.Net Core web api site in a cross-site configuratioun. I can see the cookie arrive in the Response, but from what I can tell, it's not being set by either Firefox or Chrome. Either way, it's not being sent back on subsequent requests to the API. When I use Postman, everything works great.

I've tried using .Net Core middleware for authentication cookies with server and app configuration in Startup.cs. But I get the same result if I use the direct approach of appending the cookie to the HTTP response in my controller (shown in the sample code below).

My web site is running out of VS Code from a minimal create-react-app, npm start, localhost port 3000.

My API is running of out Visual Studio 2019, .Net Core 3.1, web api site, port 44302. I've also tried deploying to an Azure app service so that my localhost web site could call a non-localhost API. Cookie still not set or sent.

Question is, how do I get the browser to set and then send the cookie back to the API when developing in localhost (or deployed anywhere, for that matter!)? I've spent hours combing Stack Overflow and other docs for the answer. Nothing has worked. Thanks much for any help!

From Startup.cs. Define CORS policy. Note the allow credentials that pairs with the web site's xhr withCredentials:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
      builder =>
        {
           builder
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(host => true)
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
          });
    });
 ...
}
```

From my controller endpoint simulating login:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FauxLogin(string Email, string Pwd)
{
  Response.Cookies.Append("LoginCookie", "123456", new CookieOptions
  {
     //Domain = ".app.localhost",  // some suggest specifying, some suggest leaving empty for default.
     Path = "/",
     Secure = true,
     HttpOnly = false,
     SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
  });
  return Ok(new { success = true });
}
```

Javascript function calling back to the API:

```
function callApi() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://localhost:44302/api/account/echo', true);
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

Response header from dev tools for faux login call. Set Cookie present:

```
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
set-cookie: LoginCookie=123456; path=/; secure; samesite=none
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Sun, 31 Oct 2021 23:27:22 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Request header calling back to API. No cookie.

```
GET /api/account/echo HTTP/2
Host: localhost:44302
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

Comment: Does it help if you set HttpOnly to true?